# Uploading Image using REST API with Cloudinary not setting the folder name

Tags: javascript, rest, frontend, cloudinary

I was trying to upload an image using an API endpoint that uses the cloud name. `Auto-create folders` settings in my Cloudinary are enabled and I read the documentation that you should just add the `folder` name in the `formData`.

```
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', files[0]);
    formData.append('folder','FOLDER_NAME_HERE',); // this is where it sets the name of the folder.
    formData.append('upload_preset','MY_PRESET_NAME' );

    return axios.post(ApiRoutes.CloudinaryImageUpload, formData);
```

The image is being uploaded but there were no folders created on the fly.

Please let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: I assumed you are using unsigned upload with unsigned upload preset?
Does your upload preset sets the folder value? If it does, it will take high precedence.

Comment: Yes, I am using an unsigned upload with an unsigned upload preset. Though I am not sure where to find the `setting the folder value` in the upload preset settings

Comment: honestly, I am not sure if Cloudinary has the capability to generate a folder on the fly or you need to create the folder first before uploading the file to that folder

Comment: Cloudinary will create the folder if it doesn't exist yet by default. You can change this setting on your https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload
To change the folder value in upload preset, you just click edit and under the first section (default) "Storage and Access" you can set the value under Folder section.

Comment: I found the issue. It was caused by the `folder` set on the upload preset settings. It should be left blank.